# java.util.logging: how to set level by logger package (or prefix)?

Tags: logging, package, prefix, java.util.logging, log-level

My app uses many libraries and I'm using `java.util.logging` for logging. I'd like to be able to set different logging levels for each library by doing something like:

```
org.datanucleus.*.level = WARNING
com.google.apphosting.*.level = WARNING
com.myapp.*.level = FINE
```

Is is possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You shouldn't use "*". 
A sample logging.properties could be such as:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.level=ALL

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

org.datanucleus.level=WARNING
org.datanucleus.handler=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

com.myapp.level=FINE
com.myapp.handler=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

And if all "org" level should be logged as WARNING then

```
org.level=WARNING
org.handler=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get it working like this:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.level= INFO

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

com.myapp.level = ALL
com.myapp.handler=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

Answer (score -1):

It would have been nice to control logging using only `logging.properties`:

```
org = FINE
com = SEVERE
```

Unfortunately, the corresponding log must have actually been created. Changing your conf file won't do that work for you.  Add the loggers yourself and it will work:

```
private static final Logger ORG_ROOT_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("org");
private static final Logger COM_ROOT_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("com");
```

Nested loggers in your application work the same way:

```
# perhaps in the main entry point for your application?
private static final Logger APP_ROOT_LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("com.myapp");

# in each package or class you want to have separately controlled loggers
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldApp.class.getName());

# in logging.properties
com.myapp.level = FINE  # sufficient to make all your loggers log as FINE
com.myapp.HelloWorldApp.level = SEVERE  # turn off msgs from that particularly chatty app
```