# Why java class not do GET request

Tags: java, minecraft, spigot

I made java script, it save/load player inventory when he leave/join, but someting goes wrong(GET request dont send)
here is classes.

InventorySync:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerQuitEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.UUID;

import InventoryGet.*;

public class InventorySync extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {
    String saveInv = "*correct url*";
    String loadInv = "*correct url*";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    @EventHandler
    public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) throws IOException {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
        //InventoryGet.main(loadInv + "?username=" + uuid.toString());
    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onQuit(PlayerQuitEvent event) throws IOException {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
        Object[] contents = Arrays.stream(player.getInventory().getContents()).toArray();
        String inv = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( gson.toJson(contents).getBytes() );
        InventoryGet.main(saveInv + "?username=" + uuid.toString() + "&inventory=" + inv);
    }
}
```

InventoryGet:

```
package InventoryGet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InventoryGet {
    public static String main(String urlString) throws IOException {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
                String response = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
                scanner.close();
                return response;
            } else {
                return "GET request failed with response code " + responseCode;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception occurred: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

The URL is correct.

For the PHP script:

**Update inventory**:

```php
<?php
//Get player nickname
//check username for exist
if (!isset($_GET['username']))
{
    die();
} else { //username exist:
    $username = $_GET['username'];
}
//get player inventory(if exist)
if (!isset($_GET['inventory'])) {
    die();
} else { //decode inventory from base64:
    $inventory = base64_decode($_GET['inventory']);
} //save inventory to file
file_put_contents('inventory/' . $username . '.inv', $inventory);
```

**Get inventory**:

```php
<?php
header("content-type: application/json");
//Get player nickname
//check username for exist
if (!isset($_GET['username'])) {
    die('[]');
} else { // username exist
    $username = $_GET['username'];
} 
if (file_exists('inventory/' . $username . '.inv')) { //find player's inventory if exists
    echo file_get_contents('inventory/' . $username . '.inv');
} else { //player file not found:
   echo '[]';
}
```

When player disconnect from server, server save his inventory, but server not do a GET request

Comment: you're doing the GET request 2 times ? Also, the get request has limit in the params. For data update, you should use the POST method. You are sure listener are well registered ? FInally, why don't simply use the yml file as it's by default included into spigot?

Comment: i using GET requests when player join or leave, this time can be 2 seconds or else

Comment: Did you give the full `InventorySync` or did you reduced it?

Comment: its full code(only urls hide)

Comment: Does it throw an exception? Did you try to start it with a finer logging level?

Comment: its not work, but it not throw an exception, idk how to start it with a finer logging level

Comment: Did you get a response? Maybe log it and add it to your question.

Comment: code(on web server) not response when you save inventory, and java class not do GET request

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21181400/7082956) can you read how to set the logging level. Maybe `java.net.level=FINEST` into logging.properties

Answer (score 1):

You said it's full code, so there is multiple issues :

1. You are in the `JavaPlugin` class, and there isn't `onEnable()` method that register listener. So, you should add:

```java
@Override
public void onEnable() {
   getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);
}
```

2. I suggest you to create a new class for listeners, to have (*I omitted import*):

```java
public class InventorySync extends JavaPlugin {
    
   @Override
   public void onEnable() {
      getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new ConnectionListener(), this);
   }
}
```

```java
public class ConnectionListener implements Listener {
    
   String saveInv = "*correct url*";
   String loadInv = "*correct url*";
   Gson gson = new Gson();
   @EventHandler
   public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) throws IOException {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
        //InventoryGet.main(loadInv + "?username=" + uuid.toString());
   }

   @EventHandler
   public void onQuit(PlayerQuitEvent event) throws IOException {
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
        Object[] contents = Arrays.stream(player.getInventory().getContents()).toArray();
        String inv = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( gson.toJson(contents).getBytes() );
        InventoryGet.main(saveInv + "?username=" + uuid.toString() + "&inventory=" + inv);
   }
}
```

3. You should not use `GET` request to update datas. The method `POST` is here.
4. You are wrongly using gson according to Spigot API. You should use `ItemStack#serialize` and `ItemStack#deserialize`, like that:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event) throws IOException {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
    String inv = main(loadInv + "?username=" + uuid.toString());
    List<Map<String, Object>> list = gson.fromJson(inv, List.class);
    list.stream().map(ItemStack::deserialize).forEach(it -> {
         // here you have items
    });
}

@EventHandler
public void onQuit(PlayerQuitEvent event) throws IOException {
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    UUID uuid = player.getUniqueId();
    List<Map<String, Object>> contents = Arrays.stream(player.getInventory().getContents()).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(ItemStack::serialize).collect(Collectors.toList());
    String inv = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(gson.toJson(contents).getBytes());
    main(saveInv + "?username=" + uuid.toString() + "&inventory=" + inv);
}
```

I added `filter(Objects::nonNull)` to prevent empty slot

Comment: I use a web server because I want to transfer inventory between servers

Comment: Oh ok, most of server will use database as it doesn't require another development, but it's always better to use post to update data

Comment: this version not work(idk why) plugin.yml is correct
upd: not saving*

Comment: what do you mean by "not work"? are you sure you didn't miss a step ?

Comment: i mean inventory not saving to file(how to use yml file)

Comment: Do you see a file like `plugins/InventorySync/config.yml`? If yes, check the content. If no, can you create it? Also, are you sure events are well called ?

Comment: config.yml was not created, now I will create, check and everything is called correctly

Comment: it not save player inventory to config.yml

Comment: the config is empty ? did you checked for event handling? (like are you sure they are called, thanks to for example mesage send from them)

Comment: yes, config.yml is empty, i think i dont use package

Comment: package not work

Comment: So you have startup error ?

Comment: no, it working but not working(plugin load but not save inventory)

Comment: Can you send the page that receive request ? I will try by myself and update my answer (but in few hours)

Comment: get player inventory:
```
<?php
//Get player nickname
//check username for exist
if (!isset($_GET['username']))
{ die(); }
//username exist:
else
{ $username = $_GET['username']; }
//get player inventory(if exist)
if (!isset($_GET['inventory']))
{ die(); }
//decode inventory from base64:
else
{ $inventory = base64_decode($_GET['inventory']); }
//save inventory to file
file_put_contents('inventory/'. $username .'.inv', $inventory);
```

Comment: return player inventory:
```
<?php
header("content-type: application/json");
//Get player nickname
//check username for exist
if (!isset($_GET['username']))
{ die('[]'); }
//username exist:
else
{ $username = $_GET['username']; }
//find player's inventory if exists
if (file_exists('inventory/'. $username .'.inv'))
{ echo file_get_contents('inventory/'. $username .'.inv'); }
//player file not found:
else
{ echo '[]'; }
```

Comment: @FinalCraft I just edit my answer, and it works for me